# Creating a site in sharepoint using powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

Iam new to powershell thouugh I know sharepoint. I want to creat a site in sharepoint using Powershell.. Found a few links but "Get" command throws an error message. Do i need to do any initial config/setting to start working with powershell w.r.t sharepoint?
Pls guide...
How do i create a site in Sharepoint using powershell...

Thanks

Comment: It's a good pattern to show your code, errors you have and adding any information about your environment that can help to give you an answer.

Comment: Please share your code or the error to help you out

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want to use powershell remoting, the command will look something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyComputer `
               -FilePath .\Create-WebSite.ps1 `
               -ArgumentList "MySite", "C:\inetpub\MySite", 443
```

Or locally:

```
.\Create-WebSite.ps1 -WebSiteName "MySite" -PathInfo "C:\inetpub\MySite" -Port 443
```

Here's the script, I named it **Create-WebSite.ps1**

```
[cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True,ConfirmImpact='High')]  
Param(  
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True,Position = 0,ValueFromPipeline = $True)]  
    [string]$WebSiteName,  

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True,Position = 1,ValueFromPipeline = $True)]  
    [string]$PathInfo,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,Position = 3,ValueFromPipeline = $True)]  
    [int]$Port = 80,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,Position = 4,ValueFromPipeline = $True)]  
    [string]$HostHeader
) 

begin
{
    Import-Module WebAdministration
}

process
{
    ForEach-Object {

        New-Item $PathInfo -ItemType Directory -force
        New-Item "$PathInfo\$WebSiteName" -ItemType Directory -force
        Set-Content "$PathInfo\$WebSiteName\app_offline.htm" "$WebSiteName under maintenance" 

        if ($WhatIfPreference.IsPresent) 
        {
            write-host "What if: Performing operation New-WebAppPool -Name $WebSiteName"
            write-host "What if: Performing operation New-Website -Name $WebSiteName -ApplicationPool $WebSiteName -HostHeader $HostName -PhysicalPath $PathInfo -Port $Port"
        }
        else
        {
            New-WebAppPool -Name $WebSiteName 

            New-Website -Name $WebSiteName `
                        -ApplicationPool $WebSiteName `
                        -HostHeader $HostHeader `
                        -PhysicalPath $PathInfo `
                        -Port $Port `
                        -SSL

            New-WebApplication -Site $WebSiteName `
                               -Name $WebSiteName `
                               -PhysicalPath "$PathInfo\$WebSiteName" `
                               -ApplicationPool $WebSiteName
        }

    }
}

end
{}
```

Comment: Whoops I misread the question as how to create a website, so here's how to do that if you ever need it!

Answer (score 0):

To write a PowerShell script managing SharePoint you have two options

1. Open the SharePoint shell and write the script line by line
2. Open PowerShell ISE and import eh SharePoint snapin and write the code

here is the code you can use in Powershell ISE:
Note: change the Variables according to your environment
first, to create a site in SharePoint you have to create a web application you can do it from this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/new-spwebapplication?view=sharepoint-ps

and to create the site write this code

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#Variables
#-----------------------------------
$SiteURL = "http://contoso:4455/" #the site URL of webapplication which you have created
$SiteName = "sitename" 
$SiteOwner = "domain\farmadmin" #Primary Site Collection Administrator 
$SecondSiteOwner = "Domian\secondadminuser" #Secondary Site Collection Administrator 
$SiteTemplate = "DEV#0" #Developer Site Template for more site template go to https://vladtalkstech.com/2017/03/sharepoint-2016-site-template-id-list-for-powershell.html

# Create Site Collection

New-SPSite -Name $SiteName -Url $SiteURL -Template $SiteTemplate -OwnerAlias $SiteOwner -SecondaryOwnerAlias $SecondSiteOwner -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: I hope that you have got the answer you are asking for, I am available for any clarification , marking this as an answer help others who search for that same to know it is the answer which helps you